# Trigger anonymous event via chrome/javascript console?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45844441/reprocess-code-for-a-dynamically-loaded-widget), I have created a custom anonymous event listener as follows:

```
function init() {
    console.log("Initiating widgets");
}

window.addEventListener("widgetInit", init());
```

I can call it using `$(window).trigger('widgetInit');` from code, however if I paste that into the console it simply returns the window object.

Is there a way to simulate the event via the console without modifying the code?

Comment: You meant to use `window.addEventListener("widgetInit", init);`. Or with jQuery: `$(window).on("widgetInit", init);` to make it actually work.

Comment: Even with removing the parenthesis, I had to change the trigger to dispatchEvent as seen in @Michael Horn's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you could try using the native DOM method:

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('widgetInit'));
```

Comment: `window.dispatchEvent(new Event("widgetInit"));` works

Answer (score 1):

It looks like jQuery is used is own event system for CustomEvent.
If you use jQuery to listen to the event, it will work fine.

Otherwise, they are (less supported) way to create a CustomEvent: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Answer (score 1):

Your listener, I think, should be:

```
window.addEventListener("widgetInit", init);
```

So `init` without the parenthesis...

When you target a jQuery element by typing directly in the console, this element is alway returned.
So the trigger worked... But I think your listener isn't working...

Comment: Even with removing the parenthesis (thanks), I had to change the trigger to `dispatchEvent` as seen in @Michael Horn's answer.